# How to remove the parentheses on this beamer template?

Tags: beamer

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {

% The Beamer class comes with a number of default slide themes
% which change the colors and layouts of slides. Below this is a list
% of all the themes, uncomment each in turn to see what they look like.

%\usetheme{default}
%\usetheme{AnnArbor}
%\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usetheme{Bergen}
%\usetheme{Berkeley}
%\usetheme{Berlin}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\usetheme{Copenhagen}
%\usetheme{Darmstadt}
%\usetheme{Dresden}
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}
%\usetheme{Goettingen}
%\usetheme{Hannover}
%\usetheme{Ilmenau}
%\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
%\usetheme{Luebeck}
\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usetheme{Malmoe}
%\usetheme{Marburg}
%\usetheme{Montpellier}
%\usetheme{PaloAlto}
%\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
%\usetheme{Rochester}
%\usetheme{Singapore}
%\usetheme{Szeged}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}

% As well as themes, the Beamer class has a number of color themes
% for any slide theme. Uncomment each of these in turn to see how it
% changes the colors of your current slide theme.

%\usecolortheme{albatross}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\usecolortheme{beetle}
%\usecolortheme{crane}
%\usecolortheme{dolphin}
%\usecolortheme{dove}
%\usecolortheme{fly}
%\usecolortheme{lily}
%\usecolortheme{orchid}
%\usecolortheme{rose}
%\usecolortheme{seagull}
%\usecolortheme{seahorse}
%\usecolortheme{whale}
%\usecolortheme{wolverine}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}\[page number\] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%       TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title\[COMPANY CONFIDENTIAL\]{Full Title of the Talk} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

%\author\[\]{\includegraphics\[height=1cm, width=3cm\]{/mounts/isilon/data/eahome/u1072932/resource/figs/q2logo}} % Your name
\author\[\]{Donald Trump} % Your name
\institute\[ABCDEF\] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
%University of California \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
\textit{john@smith.com} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overview} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it
\tableofcontents % Throughout your presentation, if you choose to use \section{} and \subsection{} commands, these will automatically be printed on this slide as an overview of your presentation
\end{frame}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%       PRESENTATION SLIDES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%------------------------------------------------

\section{Session Information}
\begin{frame}\[fragile\]
First Slide is awesome
\end{frame}
\end{document}][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Madrid` theme uses the `infolines` outer theme, which inserts the "short institute" (whatever is supplied in the optional argument to `\institute`) in parentheses. To remove these, you either have to redefine the entire `footline` template, or patch it. The latter is easier, achievable by adding the following to your preamble after loading the theme:

```
\makeatletter
% Remove (parentheses) around "short institute" declaration
\patchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@footline}% <cmd>
  {(\insertshortinstitute)}% <search>
  {\insertshortinstitute}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%       TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[Short title]{Full title}% The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\author[A Author]{An Author} % Your name
\institute[ABCDEF]{% Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
  Institute \\[\medskipamount] % Your institution for the title page
  \textit{who@cares.com} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\makeatletter
% Remove (parentheses) around "short institute" declaration
\patchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@footline}% <cmd>
  {(\insertshortinstitute)}% <search>
  {\insertshortinstitute}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  First slide is awesome
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```